# Code to calculate 15/30 minutes before specified timestamp (GMT) in ISO 8601 format

Tags: linux, bash, timestamps

I am working with a timestamp which is in the following format which I am told is know as  ISO 8601 :

2016-04-27T14:14:47.836Z

I would like to be able to calculate the timestamp both 15 minutes and 30 minutes before the current timestamp.

UPDATE: I need the output to be in the same format as the original timestamp

I have some code which retrieves the timestamp at any given time, but how can I get a script to calculate the timestamp at a given number of minutes before the current timestamp- for this example I would like to know both 15 minutes and 30 minutes before.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point of call would be

```
man date
```

There you may find the details on setting time with a relative offset, as in

```
date --date '-15 minutes 2016-04-27T14:14:47.836Z'
```

It also offers details about how to format the output.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and it works in terms of calculating the time, but the output is in a different format to the timestamp- I need the output to be in the same format as the original timestamp, I've updated my original question with this info.

Comment: if you read further down the man page for date it shows you how to format the output, of the top of my head it could be: `date --date '-15 minutes 2016-04-27T14:14:47.836Z' "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%I:%S"` but I may be mixing things up, so do man date and check

Comment: Thanks, the formatting code you suggested worked as I wished thanks. The issue I have now is for some reason the '-15 minutes 2016-04-27T14:14:47' part is taking off many hours! I created a new question for this here  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279791/command-opt-bin-date-date-15-minutes-2016-04-27t141447-producing-result