# command /opt/bin/date --date '-15 minutes 2016-04-27T14:14:47' producing result many hours before stated time

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, date, timestamps

I'm using the following command in an attempt to work out the time 15 minutes before the timestamp:

/opt/bin/date --date "-15 minutes 2016-04-28T16:58:55" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%I:%S'

The problem is the time produced is:

```
2016-04-28T10:10:55
```

Which is obviously much earlier than 15 minutes before the stated time.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be?

Not sure this is relevent, but just so you know, 
I have to use `/opt/bin/date` rather than simply `date` because if I write the command like so:

```
date --date '-15 minutes 2016-04-27T14:14:47'
```

I get the error

```
date: invalid date '-15 minutes 2016-04-27T14:14:47'
```

PS i'm working with Linux on a synology box- Linux version 3.2.40. gcc version 4.6.4

Answer (score 2):

Your format string to date is wrong. `%I` gives the hour in 12 hour format (01..12), you probably want `%M`, and then your command seems to work (on this linux box - I don't have a synology to try on).

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've update my command to the below which includes the correct syntax for 24 time, but the hour is still showing 10

Comment: /opt/bin/date --date '-15 minutes 2016-04-28T16:58:55' '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

Comment: The command is producing this timestamp     2016-04-28T10:43:55